# Unable to use a url for a permanent deleted site collection "The site address is unavailable."

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, administration, sharepoint-admin-center

I used to have a site collection of type classic team site with the following URL `https:/***.sharepoint.com/sites/businessfunctions/` and using the SharePoint admin center I changed the site collection URL to `https:/***.sharepoint.com/sites/business-functions/`.

Then after that I removed the site collection permanently from the recycle bin.

After one day I created a new site collection with this URL `https:/***.sharepoint.com/sites/business%20functions/` but when I tried to change the URL to `https:/***.sharepoint.com/sites/businessfunctions/`.

I got this error:

> The site address is unavailable.

as follow:

[image]

So currently I do not have any site collection with this URL `https:/***.sharepoint.com/sites/businessfunctions/` but at the same time I am unable to use this URL.

Can anyone advice on this please?

Comment: Have you tried changing the [Site address by using PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-site-address#change-site-addresses-by-using-microsoft-powershell)??

Comment: @GaneshSanap will this work? also thanks for the link, where it mentioned that workflow 2013 will need to be republished , but i am not sure what about workflow 2010, should they get republished also ?

Comment: You need to remove the site redirect to free up the URL. You can do this via PowerShell. See here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-redirects

Answer (score 2):

I use the PowerShell command below to change the site address and it changed successfully:

```
Start-SPOSiteRename -Identity <SiteURL> -NewSiteUrl <NewSiteURl>
```

And per my test, the SharePoint 2010 workflows don’t need to republish after change the site address.

Comment: I like to first run the command with this command at the end to verify renaming is possible:  -ValidationOnly

Answer (score 2):

It can be easily achieved by running some PowerShell commands. Open your PowerShell and run the commands below.

1. `Connect-SPOService -Url https://{tenantName}-admin.sharepoint.com`, this is to connect to the SharePoint.
2. `Get-SPODeletedSite`, will show you all the deleted items as a table including the Days Remaining.
3. Select the site collection URL you want to permanently delete, and then run `Remove-SPODeletedSite -Identity https://{tenantName}.sharepoint.com/sites/{site}`
4. Confirm the command, and then try to create the site again, you should be fine.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I guess you checked that but to give a first attempt: Did you delete it permanently? Deleted Sites will be listed under 'Deleted sites' in the 'Sites' menu on the left. There you can delete it permantly and then you should be able to use the url again.

[image]

Comment: i already mentioned that i deleted the site from recycle bin!!